# Bypass proxy using another IP address

Tags: proxy, ip

I have a scenario in which I have two computers with static IP addresses running under common proxy. And let's say computer A is blocked from accessing certain site, let's say Facebook and another computer B is not blocked.

Is there any mechanism I which allows to access facebook from computer A? If we can do something such as making request to A and then from that making request to Facebook server through common proxy.

I know that I can bypass proxy, but that is not the solution I wanted. Please help me if you have ideas, I simply wanted to learn the methods in such scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question I am able to understand that request are blocked on the basis on IP. So actually proxy server checks whether the request comes from which IP and then act accordingly. So the solution is if you have control on computer B then you can set one more proxy server on computer B and set the proxy address in computer A of computer B or either copy MAC and IP address of computer B and set it to your's, this will let computer A change in to computer B.

However, if the requests are not blocked on the basis of IP then particularly some DNS request's might be blocked for computer A, for that you should use  [DNSCrypt](http://simonclausen.dk/projects/dnscrypt-winservicemgr/) which will send DNS requests to another DNS server through an encrypted connection.

Comment: Thanx for your response:but if two of them have same ip address it will result in ip address conflict.so what i wanted to do is make request from B to A and then from A to facebook server and reverse process will be followed in getting resources..

Comment: @dharmakc 
This is a good answer, you should listen to the advice instead of inventing your own solution. 

If it's a wireless network then just kick computer B off the network for a while to avoid conflicts.
http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication

Comment: @dharmakc Yes you are right it will create an IP address conflict but only if u try to copy "MAC" address and IP address in a windows machine ,if you will do the same in Linux machine then there will be no problem and the Computer B will get out of the network and i have stated this solution as either i.e either u set proxy server in Computer B OR copy the MAC and IP address.